# Form targeting iframe

Tags: html, forms, iframe, target

I have one index.html page with two iframe:

```
<html><head><title>DOM KPI</title></head>
<body bgcolor='oldlace'>
<iframe src="main.cgi" id=main width=40% height=100% frameborder=0 ></iframe>
<iframe src="graphs2.cgi" id=graph  frameborder=0 width=60% height=100%></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

The main page is a cgi that will send an output to the graph iframe. Right now when I click it opens the grap2.cgi in other tab.

The form line of the main.cgi program.

`<form name="domformula" action="graphs2.cgi" method="post" target="graph" >`

Can someone help me??

Thanks a lot

Comment: This doesn't look good to me. Avoid putting frames in just for the sake of it.

Comment: This is a company server just for our department. The main purpose I am using apache for the window it will open de index.html page.  The index.html page has two iframe.  One frame will ask for de DOM's ip, formulas to graph and the dates. I want to graph that information at the side iframe.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here you you have a parent page with two child iframe pages. One child is trying to call the other without going through the parent page first.

You can do this with JavaScript in order to route it through the parent page.

```
parent.graph.document.location="http://yoururl.cgi"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.

I edited the main.cgi and add the line
 <script>
  parent.graph.document.location="graphs2.cgi";
 </script> 

but do not work. 
I am doing something wrong??

Comment: Thanks i keep trying and can do it!

Answer (score 0):

I can do it!

I just need to add the name of the iframe on the index.html

```
<iframe src="main.cgi" id=main name=main width=420px height=100% frameborder=0 ></iframe>
<iframe src="graphs2.cgi" id=graph name=graph frameborder=0  width=650px height=100%></iframe>
```

In main.cgi i add the following:

```
<script>
        parent.graph.document.location="graphs2.cgi";
    </script>
```

Thanks a lot!